# Questions about the summary of auto ARIMA (Python pmdarima)

Tags: machine-learning, python, arima, intercept

### Questions

I trained two models by using two different data sets.

```
model = pmd.auto_arima(data, trend='ct')
```

1. What is `intercept` in the output of `print(model)`?
   I don't understand why model 1 doesn't have `intercept` but model 2 does. This is because both intercepts' p-values are small enough.
2. In `print(model.summary())`, sometimes results are like `SARIMAX(0, 1, 0)x(0, 0, [1], 12)`, while other times results are like `SARIMAX(0, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)`. What does `[]` mean?

### Results

#### Model 1

```
# print(model)
ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,1)[12]

# print(model.summary()) 
                                      SARIMAX Results                                       
============================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                                    y   No. Observations:                   49
Model:             SARIMAX(0, 1, 0)x(0, 0, [1], 12)   Log Likelihood               -1457.746
Date:                              Sun, 16 Apr 2023   AIC                           2924.292
Time:                                      11:40:50   BIC                           2934.662
Sample:                                  12-01-2018   HQIC                          2926.494
                                       - 12-01-2023                                         
Covariance Type:                                opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
intercept   8.857e+06   2769.690   3197.669      0.000    8.85e+06    8.86e+06
drift      -1.344e+05   1.72e+05     -0.783      0.434   -4.71e+05    2.02e+05
ma.S.L12       0.2522      0.147      1.715      0.086      -0.036       0.540
sigma2       4.65e+15   2.85e-05   1.63e+20      0.000    4.65e+15    4.65e+15
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   1.35   Jarque-Bera (JB):                59.46
Prob(Q):                              0.24   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H):               5.93   Skew:                            -0.83
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.00   Kurtosis:                         7.04
===================================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
[2] Covariance matrix is singular or near-singular, with condition number 1.39e+45. Standard errors may be unstable.
```

#### Model 2

```
# print(model)
ARIMA(0,0,1)(0,0,1)[12] intercept

# print(model.summary())   
                                     SARIMAX Results                                      
==========================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                                  y   No. Observations:                   56
Model:             SARIMAX(0, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)   Log Likelihood               -1422.761
Date:                            Sun, 16 Apr 2023   AIC                           2834.512
Time:                                    10:43:18   BIC                           2845.111
Sample:                                06-01-2018   HQIC                          2842.139
                                     - 01-01-2023                                         
Covariance Type:                              opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
intercept  -5.499e+06   2509.045  -2191.829      0.000    -5.5e+06   -5.49e+06
drift       3.894e+05   1.59e+05      2.456      0.014    7.87e+04       7e+05
ma.L1         -0.3393      0.089     -3.827      0.000      -0.513      -0.166
ma.S.L12       0.5483      0.119      4.625      0.000       0.316       0.781
sigma2      1.585e+15   4.69e-05   3.38e+19      0.000    1.58e+15    1.58e+15
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   0.07   Jarque-Bera (JB):               678.34
Prob(Q):                              0.79   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H):             169.83   Skew:                             2.79
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.00   Kurtosis:                        16.63
===================================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
[2] Covariance matrix is singular or near-singular, with condition number 1.22e+35. Standard errors may be unstable.
```